# Calling Other ViewController opens a black screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have just begun development of IOS in `Swift`, and now I am stuck on one thing. What I want is to pass a string value from one `ViewController` to Other.

1st View Controller

```
// on TableCell Click


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {       
        CommonFunctions.setDefaults("a", value: arr[indexPath.row])
        let viewController = SecondView(passedData:arr[indexPath.row])
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

2nd ViewController

```
var test:String


init(passedData:String){
     self.test = passedData
     super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(CommonFunctions.getDefaults("a"))
}
```

I am successfully getting the String in 2nd `ViewController` but the problem is that i am getting a black screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting a black screen because you are initialising your `SecondViewController` with this code `let viewController = SecondView(passedData:arr[indexPath.row])`.

This is invoking the custom initalizer that you created which is not loading the `view` property of the `SecondViewController`.

There are several approaches to solve this:

If you are using storyboard you should instead of manually initializing the view controller use a segue and pass the data on `prepareForSegue`.

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("The identifier of your segue on storyboard", sender: nil)

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "The identifier of your segue on storyboard" {
        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        secondViewController.passedData = //data
    }
}
```

If you are using xibs you should use

```
let secondViewController = SecondViewController(nibName: "Name of your nib file", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
secondViewController.passedData = //data
```

or add on your custom initialiser the nib name of your nib:

```
init(passedData:String){
     self.test = passedData
     super.init(nibName: /*Add your nib name here*/, bundle: nil)
}
```

Comment: More specifically you are initializing a `UIViewController` with a `nil` `nibName` (see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName) which attempts to load a nib with a name matching the controller's class and is apparently unable to find one. The controller then cannot load it's view leaving a blank (black) screen.

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira  Then sir how will i pass data via init()

Comment: If you want to pass the data through the init (instead of a property) you have to update your `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` code to add the **nibName** of your nib. If you don't have a nib because you are using a storyboard then you have to use, as I mentioned, the segue mechanism which will give you a reference to the initialised `SecondViewController` on `prepareForSegue`.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
   self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical 
    // Cover Vertical is necessary for CurrentContext 
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext 
    // Display on top of    current UIView
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and in your second view controller

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
view.opaque = false
```